# VS Code live server error, how can I fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, server

I tried running my code on vs as live using **live server** ! but i receive this *error message* saying "application not found" ?
Anyone can help ?

Comment: There are not enough information for a serious debug. To help more information would be helpful. Is it a new installation or did it stop working suddenly? What did you try? Maybe the settings for the browser (path) or the host settings or others are not correct. Additional the browser uses an extension ... ... ...

Comment: Check the extension is correct or not

Comment: Yes it's a new installation ! it didn't work at all not even once, it just shows me that error.